# Drupal Pay user for X amount by Admin

Tags: 7, commerce

I have this project that an agent(user) is having a commission on every product that they are selling. The admin should pay the commission through the back end side by using the payment information (paypal email or any) provided by the agent.

What module should I use on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Commerce Affiliate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_affiliate) that is used with Drupal Commerce (or [UC Affiliate](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_affiliate2) if you're using Ubercart).